# formula of Gauss Legendre for 9 node element for 2D dimension?

Tags: mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials, gaussian-integral

This is maybe stupid question by im really noob in math.

Can you show me formula of Gauss Legendre for 9 node element for 2D dimension?

Comment: Actually there is somewhere on the internet (but I can't find it anymore) a webpage made by Gilbert Strang where you can find explicit formulas for 2D quadrature until 64 nodes.

Comment: Maybe you can find it here: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/fem2d_pack/fem2d_pack.html